# Snapchat-like swipe between views with a fixed background image

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/lbrendanl/SwiftSwipeView but looking to have a background in the back that stays fixed (so each view has text on a transparent background and only the text moves as you swipe)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me :

- Create a view controller that will be filled by a UIImage. On top of the `UIImage` (not inside : on top of it in the view controller views' hierarchy), make a `Container View` filling all the view controller viewport.
- Embed in the container view a `UIPageViewController` and set its transition style to scroll. Make sure to set all its subControllers views and subviews clear colored.

Then configure your PageViewController to behave as you wish